# Parsing emails from text

Tags: java, parsing, email

I have a input field where the Administrator of a web site will copy a list of allowed users/domains that have access to the website.

The list must support this format: user@domain.com,*@domain.com,*@*.

The idea is that this kind of whitelist string can support 5000 emails, which MUST be of the supported format, so I need to check one by one before saving it to Database.

I can't use Threads because I need an answer from BackEnd before saving.

I already have the regular expression to do so, what I'm worried about is what would be the better way (thinking in performance) to do so.

Currently I have an StringTokenizer and compare one by one the emails with the regular expression, but at this moment I only support 1000 characters.

I'm thinking if I need to support up to 5000 email address that would be up to 640000 characters.

This is the Java code snippet that I currently have:

public boolean isValidWhitelist(String value) {

```
    boolean isValid = true;

    // Split the white list.
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(value, ",");

    // Verify each whitelisted email.
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {

        String valueEmail = st.nextToken().trim();

        if (!valueEmail.equals("*@*")) {

            if (!validateWhitelist(valueEmail)) {

                isValid = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return isValid;
}
```

And then the other side of the coin will be when a user is login in. I need to verify if is whitelisted against one of the 5000 emails.

Is there a "right" way to do this

Comment: Why you only support 1000 characters?

Comment: That's how is implemented right now. But in order to support 5000 email I'll need at least 640000 characters

Comment: I think that the best thing you can do is a parallel processing, check the `ExecutorService` class of Java and the `Future` class, they can help you to do some parallel processing and wait until all the tasks are finished